# Getting MySQL 5.7 to show milliseconds, not microseconds

Tags: mysql

The MySQL 5.7 docs seem to imply that a column with datatype `DATETIME(3)` will store and format a datetime value to precisely three milliseconds.

[Link to docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html)

The relevant example from the docs:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE fractest( c1 TIME(2), c2 DATETIME(2), c3 TIMESTAMP(2) );

mysql> INSERT INTO fractest VALUES
('17:51:04.777', '2018-09-08 17:51:04.777', '2018-09-08 17:51:04.777');

mysql> SELECT * FROM fractest;
+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| c1          | c2                     | c3                     |
+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| 17:51:04.78 | 2018-09-08 17:51:04.78 | 2018-09-08 17:51:04.78 |
+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

In that example, `c2` rounds to and displays exactly .78 seconds.

When I try to do the same thing with a `DATETIME(3)` column, MySQL correctly truncates to three fractional seconds places, but still formats to six places. So, the last three places are always zero, but it's formatting to show the microseconds place.

```
+----------------------------+
| timestamp                  |
+----------------------------+
| 2018-04-12 14:08:19.296000 |
| 2018-04-13 14:08:22.312000 |
| 2018-04-14 14:08:25.914000 |
+----------------------------+
```

How can I replicate the behavior from the MySQL docs? If the field is `DATETIME(3)`, I'd like it to only display to the third fractional second place:

```
+-------------------------+
| timestamp               |
+-------------------------+
| 2018-04-12 14:08:19.296 |
| 2018-04-13 14:08:22.312 |
| 2018-04-14 14:08:25.914 |
+-------------------------+
```

I'd also prefer to have it be the default behavior, rather than having to call a formatting function on `timestamp` on every select.

Comment: I [can't reproduce your observations](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75dc2109105514db40ed3c8baa9e6640).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a side effect of using the [mycli](https://www.mycli.net/) MySQL command line tool. It does not occur when using standard mysql.

Comment: OK, but maybe you could give a solution which works for the `mycli` interface.

Comment: As best I can tell, this is the intended behavior for `mycli` and there is no simple way to replicate the mysql formatting without editing the `mycli` source code, which is outside the scope of what I was pursuing. My goal was to find out why the local MySQL formatting wasn't matching the official docs, and it turns out it is because `mycli` has alternate formatting for datetime fields. That said, perhaps this should be added to the mycli documentation - I'll look into that. Thanks @TimBigeleisen